# Python 2.7 Spynner cx_Freeze

Tags: python-2.7, cx-freeze, spynner

I've ran into a problem while freezing my Python 2.7 super simple script into a standalone application.

I'm using Spynner with no problems at all, however when I try to freeze my super simple script:

```
from spynner import *
```

I get these following errors when I open "test.exe" in CMD:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\MY\build\exe.win32-2.7>test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", li
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner-2.4-py2.7.egg\spynner\__init_
    from browser import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner-2.4-py2.7.egg\spynner\browser
    class Browser(object):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner-2.4-py2.7.egg\spynner\browser
    pkg_resources.resource_filename('spynner', 'javascript'),
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 882, in resource
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1344, in get_res
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Here is also a screenshot describing the problem I've mentioned above.
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9018/vfrs.png

Comment: spynner is using a way of storing data files that doesn't work when it's frozen into a zip file. You'll have to patch it to look for its javascript files somewhere that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, and I solved, share my solution,
I change spynner module source code "browser.py" line 77

```
class Browser(object):
    """
    Stateful programmatic web browser class based upon QtWebKit.
    """
    errorCode = None
    errorMessage = None
    if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
        Handle_Frozen_Location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'javascript')
    else:
        Handle_Frozen_Location = pkg_resources.resource_filename('spynner', 'javascript')
    _javascript_directories = [Handle_Frozen_Location, ]
    _jquery = 'jquery-1.5.2.js'
    _jquery_simulate = 'jquery.simulate.js'
#.....# all the same
```

than **copy javascript folder** from **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spynner-2.15-py2.7.egg\spynner** 
(above is windows path...)
 in to your build folder like **c:\somewhere\build\exe.win32-2.7**

Hope can solved your problem...